# With QT validate and split string with regex

Tags: regex, qt

I have the following string pattern:

```
(code)Name
```

Code should be two letters and Name any string.

I can validate and separate the string without regex with:

```
if ((code.indexOf("(") < 0) || (code.indexOf(")") < 0) )
{
  log("Malformed default code");
  return 1;
}
else
{
  QStringList parts = code.split(")",QString::SkipEmptyParts);
  parts[0] = parts[0].replace("(","");

  qDebug() << parts[0];
  qDebug() << parts[1];
}
```

How can I validate this pattern with regex and get the code and the name in separate variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regular expression you need is either `\(([a-zA-Z]{2})\)(.*)` if you accept letters only or `\((\w{2})\)(.*)` if you're OK with digits and underscores too. The respective code then is either

```
QString str("(AB)something");
QRegExp reEngLetterOnly("\\(([a-zA-Z]{2})\\)(.*)");
if (reEngLetterOnly.indexIn(str) == -1)
{
    log("Malformed default code");
    return 1;
}
QString code = reEngLetterOnly.cap(1);
QString name = reEngLetterOnly.cap(2);
```

or

```
QString str("(_C)something");
QRegExp reAlnum("\\((\\w{2})\\)(.*)");
if (reAlnum.indexIn(str) == -1)
{
    log("Malformed default code");
    return 1;
}
QString code = reAlnum.cap(1);
QString name = reAlnum.cap(2);
```